# Eliminar Salto de Linea en un LOG

Tags: php, log, fopen, salto-de-linea

Estoy realizando una pequeña aplicación donde le he puesto que me generé un log con los errores que se producen durante la ejecución de un archivo en concreto.
El log se genere de forma correcta, pero después del mensaje me generá un salto de linea que yo no quiero.
Alguien sabe por qué está realizando el salto de línea o como puede eliminarlo.
Les paso el código fuente.

```
echo 'Nom fitxer: '. $f;
foreach(libxml_get_errors() as $error) 
{

    echo "\t", 'Missatge: [' .$error->message. ']. Linea: ['. $error->line . ']', "<br />";
    $logFile = fopen("lb.txt", 'a+') or die("Error Creant el LOG");
    fwrite($logFile, date("d/m/Y H:i:s")." ". 'Nom Fitxer: ['.$error->file.']. Missatge: ['.$error->message.']. Linea: ['. $error->line .']'. PHP_EOL) or die("Error en el fitxer");
    close($logFile);
 }
 libxml_clear_errors();
```

El resultado del TXT es el siguiente:

> 23/01/2023 11:01:21 Nom Fitxer: [../L/1.1.1.1.xml]. Missatge: [Opening
> and ending tag mismatch: time line 6 and tme
>
> ]. Linea: [6]
>
> 23/01/2023 11:01:21 Nom Fitxer: [../L/1.1.1.2.xml]. Missatge:
> [expected '>'
>
> ]. Linea: [7]

Gracias.

Comment: Hola. El único salto de línea que tienes en el código está generado por '. PHP_EOL' pero yo lo veo necesario para separar un error de otro. EOL significa End Of Line.

Comment: Hola, si el PHP_EOL lo pongo para que haga el cambio de linea. Lo que no entiendo es porque me realiza el cambio de linea después del mensaje. Es decir, después de dar el mensaje de error realiza un salto de linea y no se el porque.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que con seguridad está generando esos saltos de línea es el contenido de `$error->message`.

Estos pueden eliminarse, por ejemplo puedes convertirlos en un espacio utilizando una expresión regular, de esta manera:

```
trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $error->message))
```

Poniendo todo junto, podrías ejecutar la línea:

```
fwrite($logFile, date("d/m/Y H:i:s")." ". 'Nom Fitxer: ['.$error->file.']. Missatge: ['.trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $error->message)).']. Linea: ['. $error->line .']'. PHP_EOL) or die("Error en el fitxer");
```

Otra alternativa sería almacenar el resultado en una variable primero, por ejemplo:

```
$msg = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $error->message));
fwrite($logFile, date("d/m/Y H:i:s")." ". 'Nom Fitxer: ['.$error->file.']. Missatge: ['.$msg.']. Linea: ['. $error->line .']'. PHP_EOL) or die("Error en el fitxer");
```

Comment: Hola, lo he probado y funciona bien. Gracias.

Comment: Me alegra. En StackOverflow la idea es, si te funcionó, que marques la respuesta como aceptada. Así, otros, en el futuro, pueden saber claramente cual fue la respuesta que le sirvió al autor de la pregunta. Más información en [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Hola, Ya esta. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

La manera correcta de generar log personalizado en PHP sin un diseño especifico seria implementando [`error_log`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php)

```php
$error_smg_log = time() . ' ' . date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . ' ' . $texto_personalizado . PHP_EOL;
$type_smg = 3;
$path_log = 'Path/Donde/Quieres/El/Archivo/nombre_del_archivo.log';
error_log($error_smg_log, $type_smg, $path_log);
```

donde:
`$error_smg_log:` es la variable en donde almacenas solo el texto sin saltos de linea.
`$type_smg:` es la variable en donde indicas el tipo de error:

> Tipos de registro de error_log() 
> **0** message es enviado al registro del sistema de PHP, usando el mecanismo de registro del Sistema Operativo o un fichero, dependiendo de qué directiva de configuración esté establecida en error_log. Esta opción es la predeterminada. 
> **1** message es enviado por email a la dirección del parámetro destination. Este es el único tipo de mensaje donde se usa el cuarto parámetro extra_headers. 
> **2**  Ya no es una opción. 
> **3**  message es añadido al final del fichero destination. No se añade automáticamente una nueva línea al final del string message. 
> **4** message es enviado directamente al gestor de registro de la SAPI.

`$path_log:` es la variable en donde indicas en lugar y el nombre del archivo para el log:

Comment: ¿por qué está realizando el salto de línea o como puede eliminarlo?

Comment: el problema no es el salto de linea el problema es lo que esta implementando ... y como lo esta implementando ... es como querer matar moscas con una basuka y que la la llene con municiones de calibre 0.50 ... usar las herramientas del lenguaje como debe der ser y las funcionalidades para lo que debe de ser es importante, si al hacer esto aun tiene saltos de linea entonces si tendria que trabajarce con el origen de la cadena ... los saltos de linea no aparecen asi por asi ... en algun punto en donde se origina el dato ... o en el proceso de manipulacion. puede haber el error.

Comment: Hola ArcanisGK07, gracias por tu respuesta.